# is there any method in polakdot.js api to multi-call smart-contract's function?

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract

Is there any method in polakdot-js api to multi-call smart-contract's function similar to https://github.com/makerdao/multicall ?

I want to fetch balances of multiples psp22 token's balance.
For example: Alice who holds USDC(psp22), USDT(psp22), and WETH(psp22). and we want to fetch Alices's all tokens balance at once like we can do multi-call in EVM compatible chain.

Comment: With PolkadotJS you have the Multi Queries function, check the docs https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.multi/

Comment: no this won't solve the problem. we cannot use multi query for contract's function call.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible. I raised this with the team not too long ago and will follow up on it. We need something like this.

For anyone new to Multi-call: Multi-call is a way for a client application to bundle multiple calls to one or more contracts in a single request. The call is sent to a single proxy contract, which some good Samaritan has deployed for everyone to use, that then makes multiple calls to the contract addresses specified in the call. All of the calls are first resolved, then are returned to the client.

One of the big reasons this was implemented for EVM chains was to limit API calls and the costs associated on services like Infura. Prices are not as high in the Dotsama ecosystem, but this is still a concern. One temporary solution is to implement a Light Client and skip third parties calls.

A second big reason for Multi-call is to avoid flicker in the UI.

A third reason is to ensure data parity between blocks. A user must be sure that all data is fresh, from the same block, and therefore accurate. If you are using React you can use a `useEffect(() => {...}, [block]);` hook that updates on every new block.